# Ability to have multiple onTouch methods with eachother?

Tags: android, overriding, ontouchlistener

The `startButton` has an onTouchListener that, when pressed, starts a media player (`mp` in my source) and makes the same button have a stop function to it.

For example:
The user hits the start button and the music plays. Then the user hits the same button (which now has a setText of "Stop") to stop the music player.

Is it possible to has multiple onTouchListener(s) within a method?

```
startButton.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                mp.start();
                timeLeft.setText("Status: Initiated");
                startButton.setText("Stop Dreaming");

                startButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        mp.stop();

                    }

                });
```

This is what I currently have... How would I set this up correctly?

Comment: I suggest you use a toggle button because it seems more geared for the task you want to do.

Comment: Excellent recommendation, what would the code for it look like?

Comment: Check the answer I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use a toggle button for this endeavor:

```
public void onToggleClicked(View view) {
    // Is the toggle on?
    boolean on = ((ToggleButton) view).isChecked();

    if (on) {
        mp.start();
            timeLeft.setText("Status: Initiated");
            startButton.setText("Stop Dreaming");
    } else {
        mp.stop();
    }
}
```

More info on toggle buttons here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html